# How to check if UWP App is running in Simulator or not?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

In my UWP App, I have a push notification code which triggers whenever Application starts but as notification is not supported while running in Simulator([MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/294eb60a-a4c7-4a49-9d2b-f019af17c613/the-notification-platform-does-not-have-the-proper-privileges-to-complete-the-request?forum=winappswithcsharp)) my app always crashes. Is there any way to identify whether App is running in the simulator or not?

Comment: Check device model maybe https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/01/uwp-device-information.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in knowing if App is running on a simulator rather than the name of any device.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to tell if the environment is Simulator. You could create a new build configuration and add a compilation flag like `SIMULATOR` and then disable the code that causes the crash in this configuration:

```
#if !SIMULATOR
   //your push notification code
#endif
```